# texstudio doesn't detect pygmentize

Tags: texstudio, minted

I use texstudio as my main LaTeX editor and I wanted to use the minted package to write code.

Compiling in a windows terminal with the command `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape` works perfectly. Compiling with VSCode also works, however, with texstudio it doesn't work. This is weird because the texstudio terminal writes exactly the same command line as the one I wrote in the windows terminal, but this times there is the error
`'pygmentize' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Of course, pygmentize is installed and its location is in %PATH%... Well, I really don't understand what is going on here since it works in the windows terminal. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: do you start your editor from your terminal or from a menu on the desktop, in the latter case what is the PATH on teh desktop

Comment: from a shortcut put on the taskbar linking to "C:\Program Files (x86)\texstudio\texstudio.exe"

Comment: See my answer over https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588006/minted-does-not-work-in-texstudio/624153#624153

Comment: @diogofriggo I kind of fixed my problem in a non conventional way : the minted package uses first a command to check if pygmentize is in the PATH and create a macro `\TestAppExists` for this. For some reason I can't explain, this is where my problem was. So I cheated and wrote `\renewcommand{\TestAppExists}[1]{\AppExiststrue}` so that it never actually check if pygmentize is indeed in the PATH. But this works, so...