# Can't use minted package in TexStudio

Tags: errors, texstudio, minted, macos, pygments

What I get in `TexStudio`:
[image]

My terminal setup:
[image]

`TexStudio` command line arguments are st up:
[image]

PC: `MacBook Air M2`, OS: `Ventura 13.0.1`

How to make `minted` work?

Comment: most likely you have set your path in  (say .bashrc) for interactive terminals but launched the editor from a GUI started from a system shell. Sorry I don't have a mac to help with details, you can presumably configure the path within texstudio or at the system level

Comment: This is same, but windows https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588006/minted-does-not-work-in-texstudio?rq=1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, it may be right because I start TexStudio as desktop launcher, I had to add home-brew (package manager for Mac) directory to path manually and pygmentize is installed in home-brew dir, so TexStudio really don't see pygmentize. How I add home-brew dir to path that TexStudio uses?

Comment: I don't use texstudio or a mac, so I can't  help much, but someone will be along

Comment: Options / Configure TeXstudio / Build / Additional Search Paths / Commands ($PATH)

Comment: @hair-splitter So, I added home-brew dir to path (/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin:/opt/homebrew/bin) and it works. But now preview of the pdf document opens in another window (external viewer) instead of TexStudio. How to fix that?

Comment: I figured it out, `Options` -> `Configure TeXStudio` -> `Build` -> `PDF viewer` -> `txs:///view-pdf-internal --embedded`. So I want to thank @DavidCarlisle and @hair-splitter for help. Everything is solved.