# Texmaker doesn’t find pygmentize but compiling on command line works

Tags: texmaker, minted, macos

I have installed pygments, but I can't get minted to work in Texmaker.

Let’s say I have the following TeX-File:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
    n = 2
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

When I run it in my macOS terminal using `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`, it produces what it should without problems: A pdf document containing solely the formatted line `n = 2`. However, when I try to compile the document in Texmaker, I receive the following error:

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag
e.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \begin{document}
                    
Refer to the installation instructions in the minted documentation for more inf
ormation.
```

I am compiling with `-shell-escape`. Apparently, Texmaker can’t find pygmentize. Do I have to link to pygmentize in Texmaker? I have the same problem with TeXStudio.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This is old, but may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48018

Comment: Are you sure you don't by mistake have two different LaTeX installation such that CLI sees one and TeXMaker sees another.

Comment: see earlier today https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668280/cant-use-minted-package-in-texstudio

Comment: you presumably have not added pygmentize to the path used by the desktop

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I solved the problem by moving pygmentize to another folder, [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62003/257667)